# How to prevent editing url addres?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, url, fullcalendar

I' m beginner programmer and i need some information. how can i prevent edit parameters by browser bar?. Look at the code. In my Controller i have below metod.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult WypelnijFormularz(int doctor, string date, string hour, string minute)
{
    RegisterVisitModel model = new RegisterVisitModel();
    model.doctor = DoctorRepository.GetDoctorByID(doctor);
    model.dateVisit = DateTime.ParseExact(date+" "+hour+":"+minute+":00", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", null);

    return View(model);
}
```

parameters are sended from here:

```
button.url = "/Dentist/WypelnijFormularz?doctor=" + doctor + "&date=" + button.start.Date.ToString("d") + "&hour=" + button.start.ToString("HH") + "&minute=" + button.start.ToString("mm");
```

Code  above is a one of the many properties which have Fullcalendar. Yes, Im usign Fullcalendar plugin to display events in the Week!(its a calendar hours!). After choosing the free term we are directed to methods above. The core of the problem is the fact that we can change the date in the browser and then we can book an existing appointment. How can I prevent this ??

I found website where we cant do that -> https://www.osoz.pl/osoz-www/lekarze/potwierdzenieRejestracji?ntrz=4295&nswd=901870&data=2015-01-23&czasOd=10:50&czasDo=11:00&platnik=0&charakterPracy=OSOZ&isGWR=false&kre8=0010&nrjd=1&s=2503261200
when you change the date, we are aware that this page does not exist. How can i got thiss.

Greetings!

Comment: Wouldn't data validation on the server side do the job?

Comment: My suggestion would be to either use another method for specifying the date ie form fields or to change your design to not be so dependent on the date as much. Unfortunately query strings are difficult to validate, but you can implement custom logic on the model itself to ensure an existing appointment is not booked again

Comment: I can't change my design, because I'm using Fullcalendar events which simulated my buttons with available hours reservation. Each event has url propertie

Answer (score 0):

You cannot instruct browser or any other tool that can be used to send the request to validate the url.

What you need to do is to validate all the input that came into the action method yourself. You can use [data annotation attributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd901590(VS.95).aspx) to validate the incoming request or implement the validation on your own.

*You should never **trust** what's inputted by the user.*

Comment: Do you mean these atributte for method? [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)], ValidateAntiForgeryToken]

Comment: Please check the link Vsevolod gave you. These attributes are used to decorate the members of your view model and will be validated on postback. In the action check ModelState.IsValid to make sure the everything is ok before proceeding. Also just to reiterate his point further... never ever trust what a client posts to your site, that is the first point hacking will occur

Comment: @rejencina see comment by PaulCarroll and I strongly recommend you to read some tutorials from asp.net web-site

Answer (score 0):

As other people have recommend, you should do something like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult WypelnijFormularz(int doctor, string date, string hour, string minute)
{
     RegisterVisitModel model = new RegisterVisitModel();
     model.doctor = DoctorRepository.GetDoctorByID(doctor);
     model.dateVisit = DateTime.ParseExact(date+" "+hour+":"+minute+":00", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", null);

     //Check if an appointment exists on that day
     if(DoctorRepository.IsAppointmentExist(model.dateVisit))
     {
           //Redirect to error page
           return RedirectToAction("Index", "Error");
     }

     return View(model);
}
```